# Remove flutter repo from GitHub

Tags: flutter, github

Don't know why flutter repositories are in my GitHub, how can I possibly remove it?
I used to delete a repository from it's settings
[image where flutter repo is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsJgd.png)

Comment: That doesn't imply you own the repo. It's a list of repositories you might have recently contributed to. Did you make an issue or fork it?

Comment: maybe I have accidentally forked, how can I un fork?

Comment: Delete your forked repository. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry too much about what shows up there. The true list of your repositories (and forks) can be found in `https://github.com/[your userrname]?tab=repositories`

Comment: never mind, I asked for github support to do that, they seem the only ones that can

Comment: I can't even see the settings tab to delete it, cause I got no access. I know it's not important but I am the OCD developer

Comment: If you go to https://github.com/flutter/flutter and click "Fork" in the upper right, it will tell you if you already forked. Ultimately you can't control what's listed there, it will list any repo you contributed to, but only you can see it; consider this to be an opportunity for mental exercise. :)

Comment: weird thing, it doesn't say already forked, anyways thank you , I leave that to support now.